# ¿Cómo puedo tomar secciones de un valor introducido en una función input para usarlos por separado?

Tags: python, input

Me explico, estoy construyendo una función `input` en la cuál yo quiero que se introduzcan los datos del día de la semana y la fecha. el formato sería "día/DD/MM". Quisiera saber como puedo tomar por aparte valores que introduje en esa función para usarlos en otras funciones (por ejemplo, tomar el dato "MM" y comprobar si el introducido es mayor a 12 para que el codigo arroje un mensaje de error). Soy nuevo en python y agradecería toda la ayuda que pudieran darme.

Comment: `texto.split("/")` te devuelve una lista con los elementos separados. Si `texto` vale `"2020/10/18"` los elementos de la lista serían el año, mes y día respectivamente. Ten en cuenta que estos componentes serán de tipo `str`. Debes usar `int()` sobre cada uno para obtener su valor numérico.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero: no escribas una función llamada 'input' pues Python tiene una que se llama igual y nunca es una buena idea escribir una función con el nombre de un BIF (Built-In Funcions) de Python. No!

Por otro lado, em método `str.split()` de los `str` permiten cortar en partes una cadena a partir de un `str` de referencia. Asi:

```
dd, mm, yy = '10/12/2020'.split('/')
```

Retornará tres valores tipo `str` con '10', '12', y '2020', respectivamente. Deberás hacerles un typecast a 'int' para que puedas hacer una comparación con algún otro valor entero:

```
dd = int(dd)
```